# EditText data is not lost when screen is rotated

Tags: android

I've two edit texts inside a typical login screen. The edit texts retain the user input even when the screen is rotated.

Without overriding the `onSaveInstanceState()` method and without updating the edit text text in the `onCreate()` when the screen is rotated, how the edit texts are retaining the text?

Also, I've not set `android:configChanges="orientation"` in my Manifest either.

I remember this is not the case with old versions. Was there a change in the API's and the `onSaveInstanceState()` is irrelevant in the newer versions (I mean to say is the OS retaining the states automatically)?

If this is the case, Can anyone guide me towards the official docs or official blogpost where this issue is mentioned detailly?

This is the case with the Radio Button inside a Radio Group, Check boxes, seekbar and switch too.

Comment: Try to restore the value in OnSaveInstance method and get the data from onRestoreInstance method

Comment: Try testing it on different device and see the response. If your device has sufficient memory sometimes onStop() doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android views whose id you mention in your xml, retain their state.

Try removing the id and checking, the state won't be maintained! :)

The `onSaveInstanceState` in the `Activity` class performs some important operations, it isn't a no-op method. This is why you necessarily need to call `super` while overriding the method.

Check [this](http://charlesharley.com/2012/programming/views-saving-instance-state-in-android) article for more info.

To quote the most relevant paragraph of the above linked article:

> To save state, the `Activity` traverses the layout hierarchy, and for each view it encounters, it calls `View.saveHierarchyState()` which in turn calls `View.dispatchSaveInstanceState()`.
>
> **If the view has an ID** this method calls `View.onSaveInstanceState()`, which saves its state to a `Parcelable` object and returns it. `View.dispatchSaveInstanceState()` then takes the `Parcelable` and saves it to the shared persisted data using the ID of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code in **xml**

```
android:saveEnabled="false"
```

Your sate will not saved.